# How to get a user using only the uID in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a chat app. So someone needs to sign up first to use the app. But the thing is when I use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function it instantly creates a user in Firebase. But the user needs to **setup the profile** too after providing the email and password, I don't want it to create the user before setting up the profile, and the setup profile function is in another activity. Also, there is a possibility that the user could destroy the activity after signing up without getting to the **set up profile activity**. The user may use the back button or home button, that way the user will be created but other important stuff won't happen at all (Like uploading a picture). This will create a user without any other necessary information (except email and password). So that's why I want to **delete the user** if the setting up profile activity somehow gets destroyed using onDestroy method. But I need the user first to delete it. I have the uID from the previous activity but I don't know how to **delete a user** without logging in first. I researched a little bit and seems like there is no way to delete a user without logging in once.

My question is, is there any way to get the Firebase user using only the uID and delete it without logging in once? Or is there any way to cancel the user creation inside the onDestroy method?

This is the signup method below:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.etEmail.getText().toString(), binding.etPassword.getText().toString())
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if(task.isSuccessful()){
        String uID = task.getResult().getUser().getUid(); //getting user's unique ID
        Users u = new Users(uID, binding.etEmail.getText().toString(), binding.etPassword.getText().toString(),"User",
                "Hey, I am Using Chatty.", "1 January, 2000", false, false);
        db.getReference().child("users").child(uID).setValue(u);
        pd.dismiss();
        Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SetupProfileActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("flag","Email"); i.putExtra("userID",uID);
        startActivity(i); finishAffinity();
    }else{
        pd.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

As we can see here, after using the method it will instantly create a user, then go to the other activity to set up the profile. But user may destroy the activity after signing up. This will not make sense, so I need to delete the user if that kind of thing happens. This way, user may come back later and try again signing up with the same email like the first time and hopefully not destroy the activity and finish setting up profile so there will be a complete user profile.

Hopefully I made some sense, please help me with this, I'm out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> But the thing is when I use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function it instantly creates a user in Firebase.

Yes, that is correct. It creates a user in [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

> But the user needs to set up the profile too after providing the email and password, I don't want it to create the user before setting up the profile, and the setup profile functions are in another activity.

If you need to store other user details that can be stored in the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object, then I recommend you store them in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), for example. Besides that, if you don't want to create the user before setting up the profile, then you might consider switching the steps. You ask the user for details and right after that perform the authentication.

> Also there is a possibility that the user could destroy the activity after signing up without getting to the setup profile activity.

Yes, an activity can be destroyed at any time. So if you get the details of the user in the first place, then you'll don't have t worry about this problem anymore.

> This will create a user without any other necessary information (except email and password).

Get the information when the app starts.

> So that's why I want to delete the user if the setting up profile activity somehow gets destroyed using onDestroy method.

You can delete a user when the onDestroy method, but I don't see why would you need that if you get the information and authenticate the user right after that. In this case in which you'll always have all information.

Comment: I wanted to make my app a little better. In so many applications, when user first signs up, he gets to type the email and password first, then comes the other profile information. So I wanted to do similar.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that all those situations cannot happen and you create a flow that ensures that.

Comment: Yes, it did help. Thanks. I was trying to create a flow like you said.